# Structure with formulas

Tags: c

My problem is that the correct value that is suppose to be stored in the data[i].Px isn't stored and the same with the data[i].Py.
My formula in the do-while is faulty or must be. 
The formula should calculate the 'position' of a projectile. 
Vx and Vy is the initial velocities/values and Px and Py is the positions (in the x and y directions)

```
typedef struct
    {
        float t, Vx, Vy, Px, Py;

    }datapoint;

    steps = 100
    data[0].Vx = (20*(cos(30)));   //in my program 30 is in radians
    data[0].Vy = (20*(sin(30));
    data[0].Px = 0;
    data[0].Py = 0;

    do
    {   
                i=1;
            printf("Time: %.2f\t",i*q5);

            //X

            data[i].Vx = data[i-1].Vx;

            data[i].Px = ((data[i-1].Px) + ((data[i].Vx) * i));
            printf("X = %.2f\t",data[i].Px);

            //Y
            data[i].Vy= data[i-1].Vy - (9.81)*i;
            data[i].Py= data[i-1].Py + (data[i].Vy * i);
            printf("Y = %.2f\t", data[i].Py);

            printf("\n");
            i++;

    }while(**(data[i].Py >0)** && (i<=steps));
```

Comment: `i` never gets beyond 2.  Unless `steps` is 2, the loop won't terminate because of `i <= steps`.

Comment: I don't see a definition for `data`. Do you have it?

Comment: just as a sidenote, the argument of cos() and sin() should be in radians, not in degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the while condition of the do while loop, do you want to have

```
while((data[i].Py > 0) && (i <= steps));
```

Oh just saw a flaw. Why are you initializing `i=1` inside the loop! Its value will never go beyond 2.

(I just skimmed through your question, so if this doesn't work I will check it thoroughly).

Comment: yes thank you... but i am having problems with my formula in the do while loop!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the notation used (since the declaration is not shown), `data` is an array of `datapoint`.  Then `data->Px` is equivalent to `data[0].Px`.

You don't show how `data[0]` is initialized.

`i` never gets beyond 2.  Unless `steps` is 2, the loop won't terminate because of the `i <= steps` condition.  Since the value in `data[0].Py` (aka `data->Py`) is not modified in the loop, you have an infinite loop unless `data[0].Py` is negative or zero on entry to the loop.

You should look askance at a `do { ... } while (...);` loop.  They aren't automatically wrong; but they are used far less often than `while` or `for` loops.

Generally, you will get better answers on StackOverflow if you produce a minimal compilable and runnable program (or a minimal non-compilable program that illustrates the syntax error if you are having problems making the program compilable).  And 'minimal' means that nothing can be removed without altering the behaviour.

Comment: data[0].Vx = (20*(cos(30)));
data[0].Vy = (20*(sin(30)));
data[0].Px = 0;
data[0].Py = 0;